# regex how to match dd mmm yyyy to select only first two digits of the year

Tags: regex, date, format, match

I have a datatable having date column in `dd mmm yyyy` format.

I need to match only first two digits of year so that I will replace that with empty and get `dd mmm yy` format.

Example `15 Mar 2019`: need to match first two digits of year i.e 20, 
if date is `20 Mar 2019` I need only to match the first two digit of year it should not match the date it should only match 20 in year field.
Please help.

Comment: Are the dates surrounded by other characters, or are you just dealing with strings that only contain a date?

Comment: You may want to look into the date parsing facilities of the datetime library that comes with your programming language instead (for example as in [the answer by Galzor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55176933/5772882).

Comment: they are just strings

Answer (score 3):

You could use this pattern with lookarounds: `(?<=^\d\d [a-zA-Z]{3} )(?=\d{4}$)\d{2}`

Explanation:

`(?<=^\d\d [a-zA-Z]{3} )` - look behind - asserts that what is preceeding is:

`^` - beginning of a string

`\d\d` - two digits

`[a-zA-Z]{3}` - space, three letters (upper or lowercase), space

`(?=\d{4}$)` - lookahead, which asserts that what is following is:

`\d{4}` - four digits

`$` - end of a string

If those two assertions are fullfilled, then match two digits with `\d{2}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/udCfmd/1)

Comment: great work. right at the target. it works fine, i just tested.

Comment: Thanks, Michal for the solution it works. Appreciate it!

Comment: @RaviRamanna You should accept the naswer if it solved your problem and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but i am assuming that you are using php.
if yes, you dont need regex for that, you can get first 2 digits pretty easily using string functions like following:

```
<?php
$date_str = "15 mar 2019";
$date_pieces = explode(" ", $date_str); //spliting by space
$date_year = $date_pieces[2]; // 3rd piece
$year_initials = substr($date_year, 0, 2); // output: 20
?>
```